# How to use measuring on (raster with kml) openlayer v3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm using open layer v3, in this script:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            imagerySet: 'Aerial',
            key: '---'
        })
    }); var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: 'url',
            format: new ol.format.KML()

        })
    }); var map = new ol.Map({
                                 controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    new ol.control.FullScreen()
                                 ]),
        layers: [ raster,  vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [5379788.7775 , 3658497.76290000044  ],
            projection: projection,
            zoom: 10
        })
    });
```

I don't know how to add measuring on the layers, the sample in the open layer only supports the measuring layer on the raster (I can't have both of kml and measuring)

If anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: all you have to do is to create another vector layer that will serve for the measures exactly as the example in OL3

Comment: i do it the same , but the vector layer of kml not shown ,

Comment: can you post your measuring code here, to see what's wrong with it  ?